# Chrome dev tools hover variables stopped working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Ive been having a strange issue in the last month or so using the brave browser but this also happens on chrome, safari etc on a 2022 macbook pro.

I primarily make vue apps and i use the debugger in dev tools, i rely on hover variables a lot to test but now these no longer work, im having to add things to watch which is ok temporary but really slowing me down.

If i swap to a personal windows pc and create a basic vue app it works fine.

Ive just added this image for reference, for example hovering over 'auth' doesnt do anything. This was all working previously, it happens on any app.

Additionally i noticed that the "Scope" section is "Loading..." could it be this?

Im hoping ive just turned something off by accident, thanks id advance!

[image]

Comment: I am also having this issue. Makes debugging impossible